# Deploying mono repo to Heroku, Node.JS, Angular 9. Heroku CLI

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular9, monorepo, buildpack

Having a bit of an issue with Heroku. I've always uploaded in one directory, but this time I wanted my folder structure to be a bit more, well structured. The problem is I can't seem to upload to Heroku like this.

I have a directory containing a folder called "client" which contains my angular 9 application and I have a folder called "middle-tier" containing the node.js server application.

I can't figure out how to push this up and allow it to work. The node application serves the angular application.

Everything works locally I just have no idea how to push this up to Heroku servers.

Please see attached screenshots of the structure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below is the error message I'm getting. Which I tried to fix by running git init again in the root of the structure. And then running the command to have a node.js build pack. Which was to no avail this also did not work and produced the same problem.

[image]

I have tried to include as much detail as I can but if there is anything else I can provide please let me know. I've spent quite some time building my application and am quite eager to deploy it!

Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, with multiple discussions with Heroku support line, at the moment it is impossible to upload a mono repo to a single Heroku instance.